# tomcat 8.5.5 tcnative undefined symbol BN_get_rfc3526_prime_8192

Tags: tomcat

I have installed Tomcat 8.5.5 with APR, APR-Util, OpenSSL 1.1.0 and TCNative on CentOS 6.7 and when I start tomcat I am getting below warning in catalina.out

I have installed tcnative from $CATALINA_HOME/bin folder and also tried installing tcnative from apache's website.

```
WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library failed to load. The error reported was [/usr/local/apr/lib/libtcnative-1.so.0.2.10: /usr/local/apr/lib/libtcnative-1.so.0.2.10: undefined symbol: BN_get_rfc3526_prime_8192]
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/apr/lib/libtcnative-1.so.0.2.10: /usr/local/apr/lib/libtcnative-1.so.0.2.10: undefined symbol: BN_get_rfc3526_prime_8192
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.<init>(Library.java:42)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.initialize(Library.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init(AprLifecycleListener.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.isAprAvailable(AprLifecycleListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.setProtocol(Connector.java:565)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.<init>(Connector.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ConnectorCreateRule.begin(ConnectorCreateRule.java:64)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1190)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1458)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:578)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
```

Any suggestions?

Mark, Output of ldd /usr/local/apr/lib/libtcnative-1.so.0.2.10 is below:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd137fa000)
libssl.so.10 => /lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f6efdf31000)
libcrypto.so.10 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f6efdb48000)
libapr-1.so.0 => /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00007f6efd915000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f6efd70d000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f6efd4d5000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6efd2b9000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6efd0b5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6efccf2000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f6efcaa6000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f6efc7c1000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f6efc5bc000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f6efc38a000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f6efc174000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6efe3d0000)
libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007f6efbf70000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f6efbd61000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f6efbb5d000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f6efb942000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f6efb71d000)
libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f6efb4bb000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f6efb296000)
```

Comment: What is the output of `ldd /usr/local/apr/lib/libtcnative-1.so.0.2.10`? Which of the above did you install from source?

Comment: Thanks Mark, I have edited post and included the output of ldd /usr/local/apr/lib/libtcnative-1.so.0.2.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Library `libtcnative-1.so.0.2.10` has been linked with `libssl.so.10`, which is commonly OpenSSL 1.0.x. You need to re-make it, to link with OpenSSL 1.1.0 (so something ldd would display something like `libssl.so.1.1`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out me in right direction. I have recompiled both openssl and libtcnative libraries but libtcnative libraries are referencing to /lib64 files instead of /usr/local/lib. Please note that I have installed latest openssl and not default openssl which comes with CentOS and an older version.

Comment: @YBS Are you sure you've specifed `./configure  --with-ssl...` pointing to /usr/local then?

Comment: Many thanks @kubanczyk and Mark Wagner. I was specifying -with-ssl option but I was also specifying --prefix and libraries were being installed under tomcat. I have corrected LD_LIBRARY_PATH within setenv.sh and I am not getting any error :-) Thanks again for your assistance.